# query using external key in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables (employees and titles). Titles has a column named "title" which has string values. Titles has also a column named "emp_no" which is external key (not sure if my terms are correct) to the table "employees". I want to select all the emp_no of titles which have only one title. And using the emp_no as external key, I want the their first name and last name using the table employees. I used this

```
select e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name
from employees e, titles t
where e.emp_no = t.emp_no
group by t.title
having count(t.title)=1;
```

but doesn't give correct results. I'm totally new to sql, so please be patient if my questions seem obvious to answer. I use mysql workbench. Thank you.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "foreign key" rather than external key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should just group by emp_no, not t.title.

By the way, use the join syntax.

```
select e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name
from employees e
join title t on t.emp_no = e.emp_no
group by e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name
having count(*)=1;
```

Comment: We haven't been taught join yet. This seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SQL! If I'm understanding your question correctly, employees can have multiple titles, yes? If so, this is the syntax you want:

```
SELECT t.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM title t
INNER JOIN employee e on t.emp_no = e.emp_no
GROUP BY t.emp_no
HAVING count(t.title)=1;
```

Here's a link to a jsfiddle showing you what I did. [JSFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61735/1/0)